# GTM datalayer reset in NextJs not working

Tags: next.js, memory-leaks, google-tag-manager

we are seeing an increased memory consumption in out NextJs app. On heap analysis I found that gtm is creating a lot of objects on datalayer. Now I tried to reset the datalayer with the reset function. I call this function when there is a page route change. The routeChangeStart event is triggered but nothing happens and I'm lost on how to reduce this memory usage.

gtm datalayer snippet added in head:

```
  const content = `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push( {'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'}
        );var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${props.gtmId}');
      dataLayer.push({platform: "${props.isTWA? 'Android App' : props.isIOS ? 'IOS App' : 'Web Page'}"});`;
```

reset code on route change in _app.tsx:

```
Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url, { shallow }) => {
  console.log(`Navigating to ${url}`);
  window.dataLayer.push(function() {
    this.reset();
  })
});
```